# Polynonpersonal agreement: agreement for noun class of multiple arguments

Tags: morphology, linguistic-typology, linguistic-universals

Among languages [that inflect their verbs for person](https://wals.info/feature/102A?iconsize=20&labels=0&v1=d7a4949&v2=cDD0000&v3=c0000DD&v4=c990099&v5=cFFFF00#map-container), a majority index both the agent and patient arguments in a transitive clause.

There are also languages that index one argument for non-person features, such as [Chechen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chechen_language).

1. `k'ant veza vu` the boy is heavy.
2. `k'entii deza du` the boys are heavy.

**I'm wondering whether there are any examples of languages that index multiple arguments for non-person features.**

Languages like Swahili that have subject and object agreement morphemes that differentiate noun classes in the third person would *not* count, since Swahili distinguishes person as well.

Comment: So you're looking for ones that _only_ distinguish non-person features, not person and also something else like gender/number/animacy?

Comment: @Draconis. Yes, exactly. A language that only distinguishes non-person features, but more multiple arguments. One might not exist.

Comment: What are you expecting that “something else” to be, apart from noun gender/class? I strongly doubt there are languages with polypersonal verbs that would have _all_ the arguments marked according to their genders only, especially when speaking about oneself, that is, about the 1st person, “I”.